# Add a button to a website to follow me without having to go to Twitter?

Tags: php, twitter

How can I easily add a button to my website that will let a user follow me on Twitter?

I'd like something that doesn't require the user to leave my site and visit twitter.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by twitter's API,
check out this [link](http://dev.twitter.com/start) to get you started

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Twitter's [@anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere).

It basically injects some Javascript into the page giving you buttons for following, retweeting, etc.